# Rails 3.1.3 with RefineryCMS with Sprockets 2.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, refinerycms

Above mentioned configuration works on development, but production makes me mad with this (after rake db:migrate, but also after regular request).

Forced to use edge versions of refinery engines, because 1.0.9 seems to be impossible to get installed without problems and with 3.1.x

```
+>> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
can't modify immutable index
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:59:in `expire_index!'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:91:in `register_preprocessor'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:12
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/papricek/blogisek.patrikjira.com/releases/20111228135719/config/environment.rb:5
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `initialize_tasks'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/papricek/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/papricek/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/papricek/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@refinery/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Gemfile and Gemfile.lock:
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
#gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer' 
gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

gem "refinerycms", :git => "git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git"

#  group :development, :test do
#    gem 'refinerycms-testing', '~> 2.0'
#  end

group :development do
gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.5.2'
# see https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks/issues/3
gem 'routing-filter', :git => 'git://github.com/nevir/routing-filter.git'
end

# USER DEFINED

# Add i18n support (optional, you can remove this if you really want to but it is advised to keep it).
gem 'refinerycms-i18n',   '~> 2.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/parndt/refinerycms-i18n.git'

# Specify additional Refinery CMS Engines here (all optional):
gem 'refinerycms-blog', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog.git', :branch => 'rails-3-1'
#  gem 'refinerycms-inquiries', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-inquiries.git', :branch => 'rails-3-1'
#  gem 'refinerycms-search', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-search.git', :branch => 'rails-3-1'
#  gem 'refinerycms-page-images', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-page-images.git', :branch => 'rails-3-1'

# END USER DEFINED


GIT
  remote: git://github.com/nevir/routing-filter.git
  revision: 1049885b01f5cfb09cee8ec7aad66abedaeb6847
  specs:
    routing-filter (0.2.4)
      actionpack

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/parndt/refinerycms-i18n.git
  revision: 859388f33017591a176788f48975ce7fcb67eee1
  specs:
    refinerycms-i18n (2.0.0)
      i18n-js (~> 2.1.2)
      refinerycms-core (~> 2.0.0)
      routing-filter (>= 0.2.3)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog.git
  revision: 26243ddade61e5bbad8f07e14b0475000da58b51
  branch: rails-3-1
  specs:
    refinerycms-blog (2.0.0)
      acts-as-taggable-on
      filters_spam (~> 0.2)
      rails_autolink
      refinerycms-core (~> 2.0.0)
      seo_meta (~> 1.2.0.rc1)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git
  revision: 713e8bc79d7c4c44dc43ce579040956e24f90011
  specs:
    refinerycms (2.0.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      refinerycms-authentication (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-dashboard (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-images (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-pages (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-resources (= 2.0.0)
      refinerycms-settings (= 2.0.0)
    refinerycms-authentication (2.0.0)
      devise (~> 1.4.0)
      friendly_id_globalize3 (~> 3.2.1)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
    refinerycms-core (2.0.0)
      acts_as_indexed (~> 0.7)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 2.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
      friendly_id_globalize3 (~> 3.2.1)
      globalize3 (~> 0.2.0.beta3)
      jquery-rails (~> 1.0.19)
      rails (>= 3.1.3)
      refinerycms-settings (= 2.0.0)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1.5)
      truncate_html (~> 0.5)
      uglifier
      will_paginate (~> 3.0.2)
    refinerycms-dashboard (2.0.0)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
    refinerycms-images (2.0.0)
      dragonfly (~> 0.9.8)
      rack-cache (>= 0.5.3)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
    refinerycms-pages (2.0.0)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 2.0)
      friendly_id_globalize3 (~> 3.2.1)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
      seo_meta (>= 1.2.0.rc2)
    refinerycms-resources (2.0.0)
      dragonfly (~> 0.9.8)
      rack-cache (>= 0.5.3)
      refinerycms-core (= 2.0.0)
    refinerycms-settings (2.0.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.3)
    activemodel (3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
    activesupport (3.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.2.1)
      rails (~> 3.1)
    acts_as_indexed (0.7.7)
    arel (2.2.1)
    awesome_nested_set (2.0.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    babosa (0.3.5)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    devise (1.4.9)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    dragonfly (0.9.8)
      rack
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.2.13)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    filters_spam (0.3)
    friendly_id_globalize3 (3.2.1.5)
      babosa (~> 0.3.0)
    globalize3 (0.2.0.beta4)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      paper_trail (~> 2)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    i18n-js (2.1.2)
      i18n
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.4)
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    paper_trail (2.5.0)
      rails (~> 3)
    pg (0.12.0)
      rake-compiler (~> 0.7)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.6)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activerecord (= 3.1.3)
      activeresource (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.3)
    rails-dev-tweaks (0.5.2)
      rails (~> 3.1.0)
    rails_autolink (1.0.4)
      rails (>= 3.1.0)
    railties (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rake-compiler (0.7.9)
      rake
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    seo_meta (1.2.0.rc2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    therubyracer (0.9.9)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    truncate_html (0.5.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.0.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  execjs
  jquery-rails
  json
  pg
  rails (= 3.1.3)
  rails-dev-tweaks (~> 0.5.2)
  refinerycms!
  refinerycms-blog!
  refinerycms-i18n (~> 2.0.0)!
  routing-filter!
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.5)
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: I'm building on the previous version of rails/refinerycms just for this very reason. While the latest features are nice, I'd prefer stability and I'll wait for the community to wrap up 3.1 integration.

Comment: Any update on this one? I have the same problem with ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2, and refinarycms from git.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the Gemfile fixed my issues:

```
gem 'i18n-js', :git => 'git://github.com/fnando/i18n-js.git'
```

Comment: Could you perhaps expand upon why you came to this solution? I'm experiencing the same error with Rails 4.1.10, Refinery 3.0...

Comment: I am afraid I won't be able to do that. This was 3 years ago and I am not sure what the errors were or even which project it was to look at commit messages.

Comment: No problem. I just have been seeing issues with Rails 4.1 and Refinery 3.0 that this issue could not address - setting config.cache_classes = false seemed to address this in environments files... but I guess it's still not exactly clear *why* this is. Thank you though.